# Android launcher icon update problem, xiaom mi mix 2s

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-icons

I have some test png image and I want to use it as launch icon.
I used Image Asset in Android Studio for that.
This [files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NOre.pnghere) were created.

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon_famous_p"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icon_famous_p_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme2">
```

I tested this on several devices (api from 17 t0 28) and everything was ok, I got icon. I have already tested the app on this devices before. The same story with virtual devices - everything is ok.

But on my own phone, xiaomi mi mix 2s (api 28) I can't get my icon. I get some small [icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMTF8.jpg) instead.

I tried to del app before install, to reboot the phone and so on but the problem didn't solve

Update. I found out that icon doesn't change on api > 26- if you load first image, it doesn't change after changing res in Android Studio

Comment: Consider the `dpi` "parameter" usage when [loading resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screendensities). Then I found that there is a default "anydpi" resource.

Comment: Link doesn't work